# String Manipulation in KQL

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, kql, azure-sentinel, advanced-threat-protection

How can you Manipulate the output of a string in KQL? For example I have a query to find loggedon users for a specific group of devices and this is an output I received. I would only want Username to show in the output.

```
DeviceInfo
|where  DeviceID== "hksjdfhksdf"
|project DeviceName, LoggedOnUsers
```

[{"UserName":"djlskjfdl","DomainName":"kfjgldkjfg","Sid":"jldfkgjfd2"}]

Comment: Hi John, if the answer below helped, please accept it (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top) to know why and how). If the answer doesn't help, please add a comment specifying what's not working/missing, and I'll assist. Thanks!

Comment: The query returns 2 fields (DeviceName, LoggedOnUsers) while the presented result contain only a single field (array)

Answer (score 2):

If your column is of type `dynamic`, then you can simply extract the first element in the array, and then extract the value of the `UserName` key, like this:

```
let str = dynamic([{"UserName":"djlskjfdl","DomainName":"kfjgldkjfg","Sid":"jldfkgjfd2"}]);
print str[0].UserName
```

Output:

| print_0 |
| --- |
| djlskjfdl |

If your column is of type string, you can make it dynamic by using `todynamic()`.

Comment: Still not working for me but thank you for the help.

Comment: Please provide a sample of what's not working, and I'll help.

Comment: This is my query:
DeviceInfo
| where RegistryDeviceTag == "Standard"
| extend AllProperties = todynamic(LoggedOnUsers)
| project DeviceName, Users = AllProperties["Username"] 

Im receiving an output of DeviceName(Correct) but I'm not receiving anything for the Users. I tried using parse_json but after researching I found that it doesn't work correctly with json arrays.

Comment: What's the type of the `LoggedOnUsers` column? You can get it by running `DeviceInfo | project LoggedOnUsers | getschema`.